# Parsing a JSON array with an automatically generated mapping throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

How can I parse the following JSON array for Retrofit? I have tried jsonschema2pojo.org but I am not able to generate model and response class. It is giving `NullPointerException`.

```
[
{
"id": "D5mQnyoLClw",
"created_at": "2017-01-14T04:36:41-05:00",
"width": 5760,
"height": 3840,
"color": "#D8DFE3",
"likes": 21,
"liked_by_user": false,
"user": {},
"current_user_collections": [],
"urls": {},
"categories": [],
"links": {}
},
{
"id": "iInYwn194Tk",
"created_at": "2017-01-14T03:53:55-05:00",
"width": 4896,
"height": 2760,
"color": "#FF713E",
"likes": 38,
"liked_by_user": false,
"user": {},
"current_user_collections": [],
"urls": {},
"categories": [],
"links": {}
}]
```

Comment: Show the logcat output and the code that created the crash.

Comment: Where is your mapping code?  it would be always good to provide what have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spend some time reading through [Retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). There are many examples to start with.

I suggest using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to handle your JSON objects.

To put it all together you can check this [post](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

try to do this but I am not sure:

```
public class Response{

private String id;
private String created_at;
private int width;
private int height;
private String color;
private int likes; 
private boolean linked_by_user;

private user users;
private List<current_user_collections> list;
private url urls;
private List<categories> listcategory;
private links link;

class user{

}

class current_user_collections{

}

class url{

}

class categories{

}

class links{

}

}
```

create getters for all variables.

Comment: But I will only a single json object from this.I am able to create this class but not able to create the array of json items?

Comment: I think You can't do to that.